# Understanding Hibernate Partial Flush behavior

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In my java application (making use of Hibernate), I see following details from Hibernate Metrics

```
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener Session Metrics {
46195 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
148413278 nanoseconds spent preparing 1300 JDBC statements;
203780356679 nanoseconds spent executing 1300 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
414686772 nanoseconds spent executing 2 flushes (flushing a total of 1376 entities and 0 collections);
325171056 nanoseconds spent executing 650 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 107052 entities and 107052 collections)
```

typical code flow is to prepare data for some target tables using data from source tables:

- select records from multiple source tables [4 to 5 table],
- do some processing, prepare data for final target tables [1-3 tables] .No change in source table entities at any point in the processing. Also there is no native query used.
- Persist records in final tables.

I would like to get some pointers as to what to look for to identify what might be causing partial-flush.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must indicate @Transactional annotation in the method you intend to persist.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the final[target] tables have foreign keys indexed in each table. this will reduce the number of intermittent collections created thus the number of collections to flush.

In my experience, if joins are  there in the final tables, it can create more partial collections as well.